# QListWidget or QListView with QItemDelegate?

Tags: qt, qlistview, qitemdelegate, qlistwidget

Let's say I need to display a list of items. Each item contains a QPushButton an image and some text. When a user clicks on the button something should happen (ie I need to get the signal). What is the right way to implement this in Qt?

After some reading, I understand that if I use a QListWidget and QListWidgetItem, this can be achieved. I can subclass each QListWidgetItem according to my needs and set them in the list widget.

However, I also read that a more appropriate approach (the Model View approach) is to use a QlistView coupled with a QItemDelegate. But if I'm using QItemDelegate, it seems that I can only paint the widgets. How can I get the push button event?

Sorry for this huge post. I'm kind of confused about the whole concept of when to use a QListWidget / QListView.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`QListWidget` is essentially a customized version of `QListView`, designed for standard cases of list widgets, when all you're doing is just presenting image or text items in a list and the relationship with the underlying model is straightforward.

With `QListWidget` and its associated class `QListWidgetItem` you can e.g. insert and remove items very easily.  But if you're inserting `QPushButtons`, then you can't use this so you might as well just use `QListView` and its (inherited) methods for setting the widget for a given index.

As for the signal, since you'll be creating the `QPushButton`s, just use

```
QObject::connect(my_button, SIGNAL(clicked()),...)
```

to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input. I understand that using a QListView is the most light weight and preferred approach. I just need to display a list of 5 - 6 items. And I need icons and buttons inside each cell. I'd probably go with QListWidget and setIndexWidget for now as it seems to reduce the dev time.

Comment: Apparently you can use a custom widget on `QListWidgetItem`. See this thread: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17953

Comment: "But if you're inserting QPushButtons, then you can't use this" This is completely incorrect. You can use buttons and what not inside a `QListWidgetItem` as long as you properly connect all the slots and signales after you create the item and then add it to your `QListWidget`. If you were enable to do that then you did something wrong.

Answer (score 7):

To differ from Matt's answer, it seems you can use your own widget on a `QListWidgetItem`, as pointed out in this post on qt-project.org: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17953.

This might be useful if you only have a few items to display and are not interested in the bother of cooking up a model class.